# SharePoint staging environment

Tags: development, environment, staging

We are looking to make a new SharePoint implementation on our enterprise. My company have defined a different domain as dev, qa and prod environments with no trust relationship. Lets call them mycompany-dev.com, mycompany-qa.com and mycompany.com

Administration expects for the SharePoint to follow this pattern as defined. I cannot find documentation on how to make SharePoint work using the defined scenario used in mycompany.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing any issue in this scenario as we had the same type of setup.Create and Configure the SharePoint farm in all 3 environment, [same way](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc262957%28v=office.16%29.aspx). But

- difference will be the user account will be different in each domain.
- Always try to keep all environment to same patch level.
- If you want to move the sites from DEV to QA or to Prod..Or Bringing down from PRod to QA or dev, In that case you have to run the migrate users as user's domain will change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install three environments for the same way , before that , you need to establish the proper environment , https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn145990.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .

I suggest you need to apply the same settings between these environment because all settings you need to apply to the production environment , so if you want to use the new feature or solution , you must do the test and audit in DEV or QA environment , if without any issue , you can apply to the PROD environment , so it need the same patch level on these three environment .

About how to move the site from one environment to another environment , please follow the below web site :

https://rehmangul.wordpress.com/2007/02/13/how-to-move-sharepoint-sites-from-testing-environment-to-production-environment/